# Customizing Azure timer-triggered functions CRON value

Tags: cron, azure-functions

We have the following scenario:

- Our UI is giving the users the option of running their tasks periodically e.g. once in every hour, once in every 12 hours or once a day, etc. The backend that runs the tasks is an Azure timer-triggered function but it spawns periodically based on the configuration defined in the environment variables:

```cs
    [Function("JobRunner")]
    public Task RunAsync([TimerTrigger("%RunningCron%")] MyInfo myTimer)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");
        _logger.LogInformation($"Next timer schedule at: {myTimer.ScheduleStatus?.Next}");
        //Do something
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
```

The value of `"%RunningCron%` is constant, and as stated earlier it's coming from environment variables e.g. `local.settings.json` file, etc.

How can we make the CRON value picked up from the database where the user's choice is stored.

Answer (score 0):

As per your requirement, We understood that multiple users may access the UI & change their CORN expression accordingly. Using single timer trigger functions won't be the feasible solution here. we would suggest you make the changes to the application UI whenever a user tries to change the CORN expression it should create the Timer trigger function using [Rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/web-apps/create-function) based on that particular corn expression.

For example:

If your application is having only one timer trigger function and there were 2 users (user1, user2) who are trying to access your application by passing the dynamic corn expressions.

- user1 has passed this corn expression as input 0 0 */6 * * * to schedule a particular task (job1) in the application.
- user2 has passed this CORN expression 0 0 * * * 1-5 to schedule a particular job(job2) in their application.

Since you are using a single timer trigger in your application job1 scheduled by user1 will get overridden by the job2 scheduled by the user2.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was wondering how I can have the function created by the REST API invoke the backend's code? @VenkateshDodda-MSFT